# how to Remove/Delete specific cookie programmatically in android?

Tags: android, cookies

I want to call web service , it needs to delete specific cookie before calling web service, i want code to remove or delete specific cookie in android.

I have Url which i want to delete cookie.

Comment: please post the code you have tried so far.  it'll be easier to help you if we can see what you have tried.

Comment: @Clayton :- I have found lot of code to remove cookie but i dint get to remove or delete cookie which comes from perticular URL. i mean to say i want to delete specific cookie. i have not try any code who delete all cookie .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `CookieManager.setCookie()` and set the cookie to the empty string like that:

```
String cookieVal = "yourCookie=''";
cookieManager.setCookie(cookieDomain, cookieVal);
```

You can also expire cookie like that:

```
String cookieVal = "yourCookie=;expires=Sun, 31 Dec 2015 00:00:00 UTC;";
```

Comment: :- in this method, where remove and delete method? and what i give the value of cookieDomain, i have just only URL and i want to delete perticular that cookie which follow this URL.

Comment: in ist line, yourCookie='', means, overwrite your cookie with empty value @mayank-sugandhi

Comment: your domain url @MayankSugandhi

Comment: setCookie (String url, String value) , the URL for which the cookie is to be set, the value of your cookie in string

Comment: String cookieVal = "";
                CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
                cookieManager.setCookie("domain", cookieVal); I have try this code but setCookie() is not available in CookieManager class? what i do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99095/discussion-between-devpro-and-mayank-sugandhi).